# Listview last item visibility goin out of screen

Tags: android, android-listview, scrollview, grid-layout

I am using scrollview and gridlayout. There are just autocompleteTextview, 1 button and A listview for result. But last item on listview are goin out of screen like

[image]

My XML code is as follows

`

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="1" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/AutoText_dest"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Desired Destination"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:singleLine="true" >

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_load_directions"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_search"
         />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/Listview_search_results"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_row="1" >

    </ListView>

</GridLayout>
```

`

Need some advice for modifying the layout. Thanx in adv.

EDIT: I just removed scrollview and run project...But still problem persist.. Output is like this

[image]

as you can see, last item in listview is half or 1/3rd displayed. can't skip it as its result from DB operation.

Comment: If the number of views in the ListView is fixed, use a vertical LinearLayout instead of ListView.

Comment: did u run ur code? @user3956566

Comment: @SK17 are the views in the ListView is fixed? Where is the ScrollView?

Comment: @arol_8021 Gridlayout is child of scrollview. Don't know why but while posting ques, error shown for code so i removed it..                               <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="1" >

Comment: @SK17 - i'm not getting your approach of using scrollview & gridview in the one, do You want a full scroll with listview scrolling ? then we have a simple solution.

Comment: ListViews are scrollable when its content goes beyond screen height. Not sure what you want to achieve. Are the views in your ListView is fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this Utility class on the internet and cannot recall who created it, if I can find the original source, will supply attribute. I have modified it a bit.

```
public class Utility {
    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        //I added this to try to fix half hidden row
        totalHeight++;

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

How to implement this class.

```
 ListView lv;
 ArrayAdapter adapter;
 ....
 lv.setAdapter(adapter);
 //set height to see all items - hack because of listview in scrollable view
 Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lv);
```

The xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    ....>

    <ScrollView
    ....
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <LinearLayout
        ....
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ListView
            ....  
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Adding this exactly like your code, makes my listview scrolling internally even though there is no more data to show, so the screen is then blank. I believe there has to be written some configuration on the Utility method, right? P.S. my xml layout includes a footer layout too.. Does this affect the calculation of the height?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Grid Layout, u can use Relative Layout. Try with below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/AutoText_dest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Desired Destination"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:singleLine="true" >

    <requestFocus />
</AutoCompleteTextView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_load_directions"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/AutoText_dest"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```